# Background image won't display at its original size

Tags: .net, wpf, image, background-image

With the following code, I can't get the background image to display at its original size (it's always a fair bit larger). I tried changing the `Stretch` property, but "None" seems to be the most appropriate value.

```
<Canvas Width="500" Height="500">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush 
            ImageSource="{Binding ElementName=w_window, Path=BackgroundImagePath}" 
            Stretch="None"
            AlignmentX="Left"
            AlignmentY="Top"
            />
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

In the image below, you can see my app on the left and photo viewer (set to original size) on the right.
[image: Comparison of size as rendered by my application (left) and a photo viewer (right)]

Any advice? (BTW, setting `ClipToBounds="True"` doesn't work.)

It seems that my problem isn't restricted to when the image is a background. The following code, in which an `Image` is the only element, has the same sizing problem. It's not just my machine having this problem (i.e. the app has this problem on other machines).

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="1000">
    <Image 
        Source="C:\Users\patk\Downloads\Bottom_wnums.jpg"
        Stretch="None"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        />
</Window>
```

Comment: What you've written above (replacing the ImageSource with a hard-coded file) works fine for me.  Can you add an screenshot?

Comment: Any chance that your Canvas above is wrapped within a ViewBox control?

Comment: @karmicpuppet: No, but I notice that ImageBrush has Viewbox and Viewport properties. Should I try to set them manually?

Comment: hmmm... I don't think it's necessary.  I tried your code above (like what Wonko did) and it also worked fine for me.  I wonder, what's the parent control for your Canvas?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Wonko and karmicpuppet. I should have tried with another image - lesson learned (hopefully :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue with images before. Nevertheless I was using PNG files instead of JPG at that time, but I assume the problem might be related.
It may be an issue with the image you are using (as the code you posted looks fine). Images should be stored in 96 DPI (which is the standard). Other values may cause the image to scale.
If you really can't change/fix the image to fulfil this requirement, you might want to check [this post from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BeAwareOfDPIWithImagePNGsInWPFImagesScaleWeirdOrAreBlurry.aspx) to understand the problem a little more in order to find the right answer.

Comment: I had tried it with several other formats (PNG, BMP, JPG), but I hadn't thought to check the image resolution - it was at 72dpi. Thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: A quick trick to fix things like that is to simply open them in Paint, then save them immediately.  Paint resets the DPI to 96.  We do that for smaller batch lists.